# Is it possible to set my PATH variable in a desktop entry?

Tags: linux, path, environment-variables

I've created a `bin` directory in `$HOME` with shell scripts that are each set up to load a Firefox profile; this way I can use a simple command like e.g. `facebook` to open a Firefox profile reserved for my Facebook account.

I'm having trouble getting desktop entries to work with this setup, though. I have a desktop entry in `$HOME/.local/share/applications` with the following `Exec` line:

```
Exec=env PATH=${PATH}:${HOME}/bin facebook
```

Nothing happens when I select this launcher. If I click on it in the directory itself, I'm asked, as with any other desktop entry, if I wish to launch it despite the lack of executable permissions. (I've already confirmed that this works as expected with numerous other desktop entries, where the applications successfully launch when I select "Launch Anyway.") If I access it from either of the menus available with my DE (Xfce's Whisker Menu and the traditional Applications Menu, if it helps to know), again nothing happens. I have confirmed that the shell script in `bin` is executable, and I can launch the Firefox profile successfully by either clicking on the script icon in Thunar or opening it from the terminal. I also have numerous desktop entries in which I set other environment variables, like `HOME`, as above, and they launch without issue no matter how I access them.

I realize there are a million other ways to do this; I could just give the full path to the script in the .desktop file, I could create a Firefox launcher with the appropriate CL switches in the `Exec` line, I could add `${HOME}/bin` to my `PATH` variable in /etc/profile, etc. (Note that adding `${HOME}/bin` to `PATH` from .bashrc does not appear to fix this, even when it's set on login and not just sourced in mid-session.) I'm mostly just curious as to whether this can be made to work, particularly for the added parsimony it provides for writing desktop entries, and because I don't want to have to expand my path outside of isolated instances like this if I can help it.

In case it makes any difference, here's the full shell script in my `bin` dir as well:

```
#!/bin/sh
firefox -no-remote -P Facebook
exit 0
```

EDIT: Despite the numerous warnings about syntax errors (since bash appears to be trying to run it like a shell script), this desktop entry also runs properly when u+x is set. That's just silly, though, and I definitely don't want to have an executable .desktop file in `~/.local/share/applications`.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the desktop files will resolve variables themselves, but you could try a trick I saw elsewhere of using `Exec=sh -c "PATH=$HOME/bin:$PATH facebook"` and see if that works.

Found at https://stackoverflow.com/a/8980518.